# Creating a new matrix of specific conditions from the elements of another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have the following sample code which generates different `master` matrix, comprising of only 0's and 1's, each time it is run:

```
R=[];
Repeted=50;
Person=10;
for i=1:Repeted
R1=randi([0,1],[Person,21]);
R= [R;R1];
end
sumrows=find(sum(R(1:end,1:end),2)==6); 
if sumrows
B=R(sumrows,:);                            
end
master= unique(B,'rows')
```

Now I need to randomly pick some elements from the `master` matrix and create a new matrix of 10 rows and 21 columns that have the following sum for the rows:

`[10 5 3 6 6 4 5 8 5 9 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 7 4 4 5]`

If the stated sum is not possible with the elements of `master` matrix then I want to recreate the `master` matrix.

For example, if the following `master` matrix is generated by my code:

```
master =   [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ;
             0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;
             0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;
             0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 ;
             0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ;
             0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 ;
             0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 ;
             0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ;
             0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ;
             0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ;
             0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 ;
             0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ;
             0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ;
             0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 ;
             0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ;
             0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 ;
             1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ;
             1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ;
             1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ;
             1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

The new matrix can be generated since the `master` matrix has sufficient number of ones and zeros. So the new matrix can be like the following:

```
          [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ;
            1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ;
            1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 ;
            1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ;
            1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ;
            1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 ;
            1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ;
            1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ;
            1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;
            1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ]
```

But if the `master` matrix does not have sufficient ones and zeros then I want to recreate the `master` matrix from my code.

Comment: I guess you need to sum the **rows**, not the columns, because size of master is 21 columns, and the your desired sum is 21 elements. Creating new matrix - applying what rules?

Comment: I need to sum the column I am sure of this point. I need the size of master is 21 columns so I put the 21 numbers of sum of each column I need

Comment: Sum the columns: `sum(master, 2)`. All values are 6, and there are only 17 elements... (they are actually different number of elements between executions).

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: what do you mean by: "*I need to sum the columns and create the new matrix that have the following sum for the columns* `[10 5 3 7 6 6 6 8 5 9 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 7 4 4 5]`"? Do you want to create a random matrix for which the sum of columns would be: `[10 5 3 7 6 6 6 8 5 9 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 7 4 4 5]` ? Is this what you're asking? If yes, what should be the size of that new random matrix?

Comment: Mr Sardar my question is to use the master matrix by searching on it to generate the new matrix that its columns have the following sum

Comment: Mr Sardar the second constraints in the new matrix generation from the master matrix is the size of this matrix should be 21 column and 10 row.

Comment: I don't understand how your new matrix is related to `master`. Give an example of your new matrix and explain how it is related to `master`. (Edit the question, don't write here)

Comment: Run your code that you posted in your question and see what `master` matrix it gives! It is in no apparent way related to the example of `new_matrix` you gave. compare the master matrix, that you get with your code, with the example of `new_matrix` and tell how these matrices are related!

Comment: If I run the code in the question the master matrix generate matrix zeros and ones have 21 columns I need to select from the master matrix the rows that its columns have the related sum if not found run a code again

Comment: Give a clear example in your question of a master matrix for which the related sum is found. And explain how you extract your new_matrix from it. Don't explain it with words only. Explain it with an example. And again, don't explain in comments. Edit your question!

Comment: Real I can not explain the problem more in my question after edit the code of the master matrix and the example of the new matrix generate from this master matrix and I think now after edit the problem is clear

Comment: This is your complete problem: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OCrg8.jpg I don't see how you extracted `new_matrix` from `master`

Comment: Excellent Mr Sardar for this image. I need matrix like new matrix in size only generate from master matrix that each column on it have the related sum like the sum of column 1 in new matrix generated from master matrix equal 10

Comment: To rephrase your question, you are asking to take elements from random locations of  `master` matrix to generate a new matrix of size 10x21 such that the sum of rows is `[10 5 3 6 6 4 5 8 5 9 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 7 4 4 5]`. Is this your question? If yes, does your data always contain 1's and 0's? Are answers to both the questions yes?

Comment: About the first question I need to select 10 element for each column from master matrix to built the new matrix the sum of the elements of each column equal the sums like for column 1 the sum of the elements selection equal 10. About the second question the answer is yes because my data always contain 1 and 0

Comment: You see the confusion? That's actually the sum of rows. Sum of each element of column means you are adding rows but you negated this in your first comment! I think I understand your question now. If you had told what you told in above comment before, you would have got the answer earlier. For next time, please choose proper words for your questions and proof-read them! I'll post the answer when free (if someone else doesn't)

Comment: I don't see this confusion but may be I don't used suitable words to explain what I need. Thank you for your time to understand my question but I need to send me the answer as soon as possible because my urgent Case now and to discuss this code with you after applied in my real case

Comment: I've edited your question with proper explanation so that it may help you in writing your next question/s !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate matrix have special charactristics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486469/generate-matrix-have-special-charactristics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:-**

I am not doing any change in the code that you've already written. Complete code with explanation as comments is:

```
Repeted = 50;   Person = 10;

NewMat = zeros(10,21);  % Initializing 'NewMat' with all zeros 
SRNewMat=[10 5 3 6 6 4 5 8 5 9 5 5 5 4 4 4 3 7 4 4 5]; %Sum of the rows as mentioned by you
SSRNewMat=sum(SRNewMat); % Sum of 'SRNewMat' Matrix

while(1)
    R = [];
    for i = 1:Repeted
        R1 = randi([0,1],[Person,21]);
        R = [R;R1];        
        % In the above step, you are growing the size of 'R' in a loop 
        % which is not a good programming practice. Pre-allocation should
        % be done instead but I am leaving the code, that you wrote, as it is
    end
    sumrows = find(sum(R(1:end,1:end),2)==6);
    if sumrows
        B = R(sumrows,:);
    end
    Master = unique(B,'rows');

    if (sum(Master(:)) >= SSRNewMat) && ((numel(Master)-sum(Master(:)))>= (numel(NewMat)-SSRNewMat))
        % Checking if 'master' has required number of ones & required number of zeros
        for k = 1:21  % 21 is basically size(NewMat,2) i.e. no. of columns of NewMat
          NewMat(1:SRNewMat(k),k) = ones(SRNewMat(k),1);  %Replacing 0's with 1's in NewMat
          NewMat(:,k)= NewMat(randperm(10),k); %Shuffling the rows of kth column  of NewMat
          %In the above line, 10 is basically size(NewMat,1) i.e. no. of rows of NewMat
        end
        break; %No need to run again if mentioned sum is possible
    end
end
NewMat
```

**Output:-**

One of the outputs that it generated when I ran this code is shown below:

```
NewMat =

  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1
  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1
  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1
  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1
  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1  0
  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1
```